# Visual Studio: "error LNK2005: _strchr already defined" while using /MT

Tags: c++

I'm building an application in Visual Studio but have had no luck running it on other computers. When I attempt to compile the project in /MT as the runtime library, I still get the following output:

```
error LNK2005: _strrchr already defined in LIBCMT.lib(strrchr.obj)
warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I don't know why I'm still getting these messages when I've switched the runtime library from /MD to /MT. Most solutions to this error message involve simply switching runtime libraries, but I've already done that. The only other library I'm using is SDL 1.2.

Comment: You have to set `/MT` for the other library as well. Or you can pack redistributable CRT dlls with your program.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a static SDL library? I assume the problem is that you are linking with another static library that have been compiled with /MD or /MDd. Make sure that all library dependencies (and all their dependencies) have been compiled with /MT.